# Tryping to compile TypeScript for Angular with Gulp

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, gulp

I'm trying to learn TypeScript and Gulp, but I cant seem to get the basics working..

gulpfile.ts:

```
"use strict";

const gulp = require("gulp");
const del = require("del");
const tsc = require("gulp-typescript");
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const tsProject = tsc.createProject("tsconfig.json");

/**
* Remove build directory.
*/
gulp.task('clean', (cb) => {
    return del(["build"], cb);
});

/**
* Compile TypeScript sources and create sourcemaps in dist directory.
*/
gulp.task("compile", () => {
    let tsResult = gulp.src("src/**/*.ts")
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(tsc(tsProject));
    return tsResult.js
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write(".", {sourceRoot: '/src'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("dist"));
});

/**
* Copy all required libraries into dist directory.
*/
gulp.task("libs", () => {
    return gulp.src([
        'core-js/client/shim.min.js',
        'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
        'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
        'reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',
        'rxjs/**',
        'zone.js/dist/**',
        '@angular/**'
    ], {cwd: "node_modules/**"}) /* Glob required here. */
    .pipe(gulp.dest("dist/lib"));
});

/**
* Copy all resources that are not TypeScript files into dist directory.
*/
gulp.task("resources", () => {
    return gulp.src(["src/**/*", "!**/*.ts"])
    .pipe(gulp.dest("dist"));
});

/**
* Watch for changes in TypeScript, HTML and CSS files.
*/
gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch(["src/**/*.ts"], ['compile']).on('change', function (e) {
        console.log('TypeScript file ' + e.path + ' has been changed. Compiling.');
    });

    gulp.watch(["src/**/*.html", "src/**/*.css"], ['resources']).on('change', function (e) {
        console.log('Resource file ' + e.path + ' has been changed. Updating.');
    });
});

/**
* Build the project.
*/
gulp.task("build", ['compile', 'resources', 'libs'], () => {
    console.log("Building the project ...");
});
```

- My folder structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWCBs.png
- gulpfile.ts: https://pastebin.com/mJwT3RVF
- main.ts: https://pastebin.com/5ShRiZUy
- app.module.ts: https://pastebin.com/LsZqK1uC
- app.component.ts: https://pastebin.com/LW1BQu71
- Output: https://pastebin.com/gujyp3zR

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I would suggest using the `@angular/cli` which has `ng build`, `ng server`, and other commands to do this for you. Otherwise, you can use `ngc` (instead of `tsc`) to compile.

Comment: Try to learn them one at a time. First learn JavaScript, then learn TypeScript. Then learn how to compile files with `tsc`. Then pick up frameworks and build tools.

Comment: The first thing you are doing wrong is providing links instead of code.

Comment: @TheHeadRush I'm sorry I've used Stackoverflow for ages but this is my first time ever asking a question.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I know JavaScript and I know Angular pretty well. I have compiled basic TypeScript with Gulp before (just simple functions and such). But I don't understand the more advanced stuff like modules and using Angular with it.

Comment: @ExplosionPills So I shouldn't use Gulp to compile?

Comment: @NoëlHagestein that is not what I am saying. Since you are already familiar with pre-module JavaScript, familiarize yourself with ES Modules, and with TypeScript. One question, as Angular practically _requires_ TypeScript, how can you already be familiar with it? (note that Angular is not AngularJS vs 2.0 (such a thing never came to be), but an unrelated framework).